# when I try to upload image in payload shoing error

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I am using rtk query for client side and backend node express mongodb. I have to upload image to cloudinary.
When I post request rtk fetchBaseQuery in payload showing some image text and 400 Bad Request status

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
// profile page
const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", imgFile);
  await uploadImg(formData).unwrap();
```

```
// uploadImgApi.js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const uploadImgApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "uploadImgApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:5000",
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState, endpoint }) => {
      const { token } = getState().user;
      if (token) {
        headers.set("Authorization", `${token}`);
        headers.set("content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
      }
      return headers;
    },
    credentials: "include",
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    uploadImg: builder.mutation({
      query(file) {
        return {
          url: `/upload/upload_avatar`,
          method: "POST",
          body: file,
          credentials: "include",
        };
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useUploadImgMutation } = uploadImgApi;
```

Comment: Did you checked is this working fie in POSTMAN?

Comment: Yes api is working properly in postman

Comment: Can you try using IP address of your system instead passing localhost?

Comment: tried but nothing same problem

Comment: Its working with axios and postman

Comment: Solved : https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/2287#issuecomment-1111213377